# capture directory as string javaforms

Tags: java, directory

I´m working on a directory creator program in java, I can now create the new folder, but I can not give the user the capacity to select the directory where this folder will be created.

I´m currently working on netbeans with javaforms.

Thanks in forward.

Answer (score 0):

The user has to input the given path via command line or gui as string x.
After that, the program must check if this path exists.
If this is true, the directory name to create is: "x" + File.separator +"newFolderName".